# Spring boot - Oracle - error al usar multi schema con jpa

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Necesito leer una base de datos que se encuentra en otro schema diferente al que estoy usando. Entonces googleando encontré estos 2 tutoriales de como configurar 2 datasources en spring boot (https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7 y https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases). 
Mi aplicación es un api rest hecho en spring-boot con jpa/hibernate y oracle. Al levantar tomcat me sale este error y aborta:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

**Description:**

> 2019-07-02 19:29:54.720 ERROR 780 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.

Les pongo mis clases de configuración. Si falta alguna me la piden por favor.
Esta clase configura un datasource

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.adalove.gestor.core.dao.model.genesys", entityManagerFactoryRef = "genesysEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "genesysTransactionManager")
public class PersistenceGenesysAutoConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public PersistenceGenesysAutoConfiguration() {
        super();
    }

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean genesysEntityManager() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(genesysDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.adalove.gestor.core.dao.model.genesys");

    final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    //properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.second-datasource")
public DataSource genesysDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager genesysTransactionManager() {
    final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(genesysEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

}
```

Esta clase configura el otro `datasource`:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
basePackages = "com.adalove.gestor.core.dao.repository.gestor",
entityManagerFactoryRef = "gestorEntityManager",
transactionManagerRef = "gestorTransactionManager"
    )
public class PersistenceGestorAutoConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

public PersistenceGestorAutoConfiguration() {
    super();
}

@Primary
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource gestorDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Primary
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean gestorEntityManager() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(gestorDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.adalove.gestor.core.dao.model.gestor");

    final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    //properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
}

@Primary
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager gestorTransactionManager() {
    final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(gestorEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
}
```

Esta es la parte del `application.properties` de donde toma las propiedades:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.44:1521:XE
spring.datasource.username=GESTOR
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

## Configuracion a GENESYS
spring.second-datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.44:1521:XE
spring.second-datasource.username=GENCONF
spring.second-datasource.password=password
```

La clase `CustomUserDetailsService` que menciona que supuestamente tiene el error es la siguiente:

```
package com.adalove.gestor.core.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import 
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.adalove.gestor.core.dao.model.gestor.User;
import com.adalove.gestor.core.dao.repository.gestor.UserRepository;
import com.adalove.gestor.core.exception.AppException;

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String usernameOrEmail)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.findByUsernameOrEmail(usernameOrEmail, usernameOrEmail)
            .orElseThrow(() -> 
                    new UsernameNotFoundException("No se encontró un usuario con el nombre: " + usernameOrEmail)
    );

    if (!user.isActive())
        throw new AppException("El Usuario no se encuentra activo!.");

    return UserPrincipal.create(user);
}

// This method is used by JWTAuthenticationFilter
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserById(Long id) {
    User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
        () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with id : " + id)
    );

    return UserPrincipal.create(user);
}
}
```

Bueno, espero me puedan ayudar...estoy bastante desesperado porque los artículos que puse de referencia no parecen complicados pero proyecto no anda y no encuentro mucha mas información de como usar dos schemas distintos en spring boot. GRACIAS

Comment: Ahi encontré que los basePackages de las 2 clases de configuración de los datasources tenian mal valor. Despues de actualizarlo y volver a ejecutar persiste un error pero cambió...ahora el error es 2019-07-02 19:29:54.720 ERROR 780 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres acceder a tablas de otro esquema es mucho más sencillo que, con el usuario de tu datasource, crees sinónimos a las tablas que quieres acceder y le des permisos al usuario.

Por ejemplo, si tu aplicación se conecta con el usuario CARS (del esquema CARS) y quieres acceder al esquema CYCLES:

Con el usuario CYCLES das permisos al usuario CARS:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE TO CYCLES.TABLE1 TO CARS;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE TO CYCLES.TABLE2 TO CARS;
...
```

Con el usuario CARS creas sinónimos a esas tablas:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM TABLE1 FOR CYCLES.TABLE1;
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM TABLE2 FOR CYCLES.TABLE2;
...
```

De esta manera, con el usuario CARS puedes hacer queries sobre la tabla `CYCLES.TABLE1` como `TABLE1`:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
```

Y quién dice queries, dice implementar entidades Java que hagan referencia a esta tabla.

Te ahorras tener dos datasources, configurarlos y demás.